# In which language is www.audiotool.com programmed?

Tags: audio, html5-audio

Im learning to code web stuff. ruby,javascript...

I would like to do something that makes noise like www.audiotool.com

The app is basically a DAW, digital audio workstation, is fast and sounds good... you can eveb use samples and save projects in the cloud.

But my main question is which languages or tools can make an app like this ?

but i don't know which languages make this kind of apps posible ?

is it creating the sound in the browser, or in a server and sending it back ?
any guesses?

Comment: From what I see in the source, it mainly uses flash... There are actually not a lot of client-side technologies to use in a browser...

Comment: You can do similar stuff with the Web Audio API now. Just Google "Web Audio API". Your browser has a synthesis engine built in !! You can program Web Audio API in JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Audiotool.com uses flash to synthesize audio. Their FAQ says that you should update your flash player if you're having trouble, so that seems like a pretty strong indication that they use flash.

However, if you want to make music apps, I would advise against using flash. Newer devices and operating systems will drop support for flash (iPhones/iPads already don't support flash, I believe).

If you want a future-proofed music-making solution, you can do that all client-side in javascript with the web-audio api.

I have authored, and actively maintain a javascript library that aims to simplify the process of building complex apps with the web audio api. If you're just getting started with making music on the web, you might want to check it out. The web audio api is not terribly beginner-friendly, in my opinion.  https://github.com/rserota/wad

Comment: I'm happy to help! If you feel like this sufficiently answers your question, please select it as the chosen answer.